# Display words in c++ sentences

Tags: c++, string, char

I have faced a question where we have to display the words in c++ but:the output format is different
I have used string stream for displaying words but I am not getting a clear idea on how to display in the following format. Can somebody please suggest an idea on how to do this question.
The output should display the sentences in double quotes as it is.
Example:

input:

```
hi hello "hello world" how are you?
```

output:

```
hi 

hello

"hello world"

how
 
are

you?
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, C and C++ are different languages. Please do not tag both unless you are asking about differences or combination of both

Comment: Please read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates where exactly you are stuck in your question. You can edit the question to include the missing information. Especially for homework questions, read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: first split the string with `'"'` as delimiter, then split the substrings not eclosed by `"` with `' '` as delimiter. Do you know how to split a string?

Comment: Do you know how to split a string? that question was enough thank you very much i understood how to it.solved it